# Can't run the server with debug Vue3 Vite app in Docker with VS Code

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vscode-debugger, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to setup development environment and run Vue3 Vite app inside Docker container. I also would like to have ability to "attach" to that app and make use of VS Code debugging. I found some info how to do that, but after I implemented these changes the app is not openning anymore, the page is blank when I go to website. The port (8080) is open, I checked it with telnet.

This is what I've done:

`package.json`

```
"debug": "node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js",
```

`vite.config.js`

```
server: {
...
hmr: { host: '0.0.0.0' },
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```
EXPOSE $VITE_PORT 9229
CMD  npm run debug
```

There is no errors in docker logs.

```
> frontoffice@0.0.0 debug
> node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js

Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/53fba2df-2147-4ed4-a493-daa9ff2b3a88
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 1037 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
Debugger ending on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/53fba2df-2147-4ed4-a493-daa9ff2b3a88
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(venv) user:~/project/frontoffice$
```

UPDATE:

1. `npm run dev` works inside docker
2. tried both `--inspect` and `--inspect-brk`
3. works if I run `npm run debug` locally, without docker
4. `netstat` from docker

```
root@c87845a98941:/app# netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:39369        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9229            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:56572        0.0.0.0:*
```

5. `telnet localhost 8080` from host

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: maybe you need to specify the port for vite see vite is running at `8080` not `9229`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. 8080 - vite port and 9229 port for debugging. I'm trying to access the app via `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it working, I needed `--host` flag

```
"debug": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js --host --port 8080"
```